# Segmentation fault when call 0x16

Tags: linux, interrupt, assembly

Here is piece of my nasm code:

```
extern printf

%macro print 2
        mov  rdi, %1
        mov  rsi, %2
        mov  rax, 0
        call printf
%endmacro

section .data

        msg1:   db 'Nasm', 0
        len1:   equ $ - msg1
        fmts:   db "%s", 10, 0 ; printf format string 
        fmti:   db "%d", 10, 0

section .bss           ;Uninitialized data
   num resb 5

section  .text
        global main    ; declaring for gcc
main:
        push    rbp            ; save rbp

        print   fmts, msg1
        xor     ah, ah
        int     0x16
        print   fmti, [num]

exit:
        leave
        mov     rax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
        int     0x80        ;call kernel
```

Output:

```
[b@l .K]$ nasm test.asm -f elf64 -o test.o && gcc test.o -o test && ./test
Nasm
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Whan I replace:

```
        print   fmts, msg1
        print   fmti, [num]
        xor     ah, ah
        int     0x16
```

then

```
[b@l .K]$ nasm test.asm -f elf64 -o test.o && gcc test.o -o test && ./test
Nasm
0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

int 0x80 works greatly but 0x16 crush my code. I'm on fedora 29, Intel core i5

Comment: What do you think int 0x16 is going to do?

Comment: wait for keyboard

Comment: Hover your mouse of ther the `[assembly]` tag at the bottom of your Q and read thru it. You need to add another tag to your Q. (I didn't downvote). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> int 0x80
> ```

The `int`, `sysenter` and `syscall` instructions are special variants of a `call` instruction:

These instructions call a special function, a so-called "handler".

`int 0x80` is a handler in the Linux operating system intended for 32-bit Linux programs. Calling `int 0x80` from 64-bit programs (and your program obviously is 64-bit) *may* work, but it *may* also not work.

In 64-bit Linux you use `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`. The `exit` system call should (*) look like this:

```
mov $60, %rax  # In 64-bit Linux sys_exit is 60, not 1
mov $0, %rdi   # Exit code; this would be %ebx in 32-bit Linux
syscall
```

`int 0x16` is a handler in the BIOS. You can only call BIOS handlers from 16-bit real-mode (**) programs. You can neither call this handler from 32- nor from 64-bit programs.

---

(*) Unfortunately, I have written assembly programs for 32-bit Linux only, so I'm not sure if this is correct.

(**) The CPU supports two different operating modes when executing 16-bit code. BIOS handlers will only work in one of these two modes.

---

> wait for keyboard

In Linux there are no explicit keyboard functions.

You have to use the `termios` functions to switch the behavior of the `stdin` file handle (file handle 0). In assembler, this would be done by a `sys_ioctl` call.

The default behavior is that Linux processes the input line-wise (e.g. if you press "AB"+"backspace"+"CD"+"enter", Linux will return "ACD"+"enter" to the program).

The default behavior is also that `sys_read` will wait until some data is available. Using `termios` you may change this behavior in a way that all keyboard presses are returned to the program and/or that `sys_read` will not wait for input.

Then you call `sys_read` to read from `stdin`.

Comment: You say: _You can neither call this handler from 32- nor from 64-bit programs._ But how can I use it or what do I need to use instead of it?

Comment: @БогуславПавлишинець You have to use the appropriate interface provided by Linux.  In your case, call `read` on `stdin`.

Comment: @БогуславПавлишинець No chance to call `int 0x16` from a Linux program. You might write a 16-bit program for MS-DOS and run this in an MS-DOS emulation. (In this case, you cannot call `int 0x80` but MS-DOS functions like `int 0x21`. And you'll have to use 16-bit code, of course.) There is no possibility to access the keyboard directly under Linux. In a console program you can only use the standard input (`termios`, `sys_ioctl` and `sys_read`) to read input passed to the program.

Comment: Actually, there are five execution modes where 16 bit code can be executed, six if you count unreal mode as separate: real mode, SMM mode, virtual 8086 mode, 16 bit protected mode, and 16 bit compatibility mode while the processor is in  long mode.